# How to print page number while printing pdf by jQuery print method?

Tags: jquery, css, pdf

I am printing a webpage by jQuery print method, and I am trying to print the page number in a place on the page, but I did not succeed.

Comment: what you tried so far .?

Comment: Hi Aman , I trying this code but not succeed  

#pageFooter:after {
    counter-increment: page;
    content: counter(page);
}

Comment: try this library 
https://github.com/menusal/printMe

Comment: See this code.
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1BYHPGFGOGT
its working fine without a library
at the bottom of the page you can see the page numbers.
thanks, Hope it works